# Conceal features in init.lua

Tags: neovim, conceal, vimscript-lua, init.lua

The Neovim user guide [says](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_01.html#usr_01.txt) to issue these commands to show the concealed characters in the user guide:

```
:set conceallevel=0
:hi link HelpBar Normal
:hi link HelpStar Normal
```

What would be the equivalent init.lua lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
vim.o.conceallevel = 0
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "HelpBar", { link = "Normal" })
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, "HelpStar", { link = "Normal" })
```

The [nvim_set_hl](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_set_hl()) documentation contains a remark about the link argument of a highlighting group in the description of the val parameter.

Comment: where do I find that in the documentation?

Comment: Not easy to search the doc and a good knowledge of the vimscript version help to understand the lua version. I have added a pointer to the doc. Tell us if it help enough.